# Unity3D Grid Tilemap - how to catch mouse events?

Tags: unity-game-engine, events, 2d

I have scene, camera, object with Grid component and childs with Tilemap+TilemapRenderer components, and then script on Grid object.

I need to catch mouse events (and then detect cell, i know how to do it) on these objects. Not `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` in update lifecycle, i need event-style handling for it.
How can i make it?

Ive tried colliders on tilemaps/grid and MonoBeha:OnMouseDown method, tried methods from IPointerEnterHandler (and another form package), and raycasts. Nothing worked...

I really confused, i should make myown event system from `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`?

Comment: You must attach collider to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while
>   over the GUIElement or Collider.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

So if you want to use `OnMouseDown` you could add a BoxCollider2D to your Grid or Tilemap (You may have to check `IsTrigger` if it ends up pushing away other objects)

I just tried adding a collider and a small script on both a Grid and a Tilemap and it works fine

```
public void OnMouseDown()
{ 
    Debug.Log("Boom!");
}
```

Comment: Oh crap... Ive used few another collider but not BoxCollider2D... Thanks mate!